# Is there a way to guarantee case class copy methods exist with type classes in Scala?

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros

In the example below I have a type class `Foo`, and would like to somehow guarantee that all members conforming to `Foo` (such as `Bar` via `barFoo`) have a copy method such as the one generated by way of being a `case class`. I haven't thought of a way to do this. In this case the copy signature would be possibly be something like `copy(foo: F, aa: List[T] = foo.aa, maybe: Option[T] = foo.maybe): F`.

```
trait Foo[F] {
  type T
  def aa(foo: F): List[T]
  def maybe(foo: F): Option[T]
}

final case class Bar(aa: List[String], maybe: Option[String])
object Bar {
  implicit val barFoo = new Foo[Bar] {
    type T = String
    def aa(foo: Bar): List[String] = foo.aa
    def maybe(foo: Bar): Option[T] = foo.maybe
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do it with type member, but here you are a version with type parameters. Also it is necessary to add a method to Foo to construct the object.

```
trait Foo[F, T] {
  def aa(foo: F): List[T]
  def maybe(foo: F): Option[T]
  def instance(aa: List[T], maybe: Option[T]): F
}

class Bar(val aa: List[String], val maybe: Option[String]) {
  override def toString = s"Bar($aa, $maybe)"
}

object Bar {
  implicit val barFoo = new Foo[Bar, String] {
    def aa(foo: Bar): List[String] = foo.aa
    def maybe(foo: Bar): Option[String] = foo.maybe
    def instance(aa: List[String], maybe:Option[String]):Bar = new Bar(aa, maybe)
  }
}

implicit class FooOps[A, T](fooable:A)(implicit foo:Foo[A, T]) {

  def copy(aa: List[T] = foo.aa(fooable), maybe: Option[T] = foo.maybe(fooable)) = {
    foo.instance(aa, maybe)
  }

}

val r = new Bar(List(""), Option("")).copy(aa = List("asd"))

println(r)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to adapt it to my situation. It looks like I'm close. Was the error shown here similar to what you had for the type member? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226284/can-a-type-conflict-between-typeclass-evidence-parameter-and-concrete-instance-p

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. Make the type class public in order to use its type member gave me that error.