# Can a type conflict between typeclass evidence parameter and concrete instance parameter be resolved?

Tags: scala

In [Is there a way to guarantee case class copy methods exist with type classes in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214333/is-there-a-way-to-guarantee-case-class-copy-methods-exist-with-type-classes-in-s/52214823#52214823), I had a related question posed where this new problem came up. Unfortunately, for obscure reasons, I need type parameters.

My typeclass and implicit ops class look like:

```
  trait Job[J] {
    def id(jb: J): JobId
    def cmd(jb: J): String
    type M <: JobMetaData
    type JRef = J
    def meta(jb: J): M
    def pickler: Pickler[J]
    def rw: RW[J]
    def instance(jb: J, id: JobId, cmd: String, meta: M): J
  }
  object Job{

    type Aux[J0, M0] = Job[J0] {type M = M0}
    implicit class JobDispatch[J](val job: J)(implicit val ev: Job[J]) {
      def id: JobId = ev.id(job)
      def cmd: String = ev.cmd(job)
      def meta: ev.M = ev.meta(job)
      def rw: RW[J] = ev.rw
      def copyJob(
        idIn: JobId = job.id,
        cmdIn: String = job.cmd,
        metaIn: ev.M = job.meta
      ): J = ev.instance(job, idIn, cmdIn, metaIn)
    }

}
```

Of note are the `instance` and `copyJob` methods; `copyJob` is meant to be the public API.

Now for a concrete example, I have:

```
  final case class OneShot(id: JobId, cmd: String, meta: SysJobMetaData) {
    type M = SysJobMetaData
  }

  object OneShot{
    implicit val rw: RW[OneShot] = macroRW
    implicit val jobOneShot: Job.Aux[OneShot, SysJobMetaData] = new Job[OneShot] {
      def id(jb: OneShot): JobId = jb.id
      def cmd(jb: OneShot): String = jb.cmd
      override type M = SysJobMetaData
      def meta(jb: OneShot): M = jb.meta
      val pickler: Pickler[OneShot] = generatePickler
      val rw: RW[OneShot] = OneShot.rw
      def instance(jb: OneShot, id: JobId, cmd: String, meta: M): OneShot =
        jb.copy(id, cmd, meta)
    }
```

But this gives the error:

```
[error] /home/brandon/workspace/CCRS/model/src/main/scala/org/xsede/jobrunner/model/ModelApi.scala:277: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : _1.ev.M where val _1: org.xsede.jobrunner.model.ModelApi.Job.JobDispatch[J]
[error]  required: JobDispatch.this.ev.M
[error]         metaIn: ev.M = job.meta
[error]                            ^
```

First, I don't think I exactly understand the error. It seems to be that `job.meta` should resolve to type `ev.M`. Can this be resolved?

**Edit 1**

If I add an `asInstanceOf` call to make things happy locally in the `copyJob` definition (`= ev.instance(job, idIn, cmdIn, metaIn.asInstanceOf[ev.M])`), things look happier locally but type information is lost; `M <: JobMetaData`, but the original class is perhaps unsurprisingly not recovered, including members showing up in classes extending `JobMetaData`, like `shell` below:

```
value shell is not a member of _1.ev.M
[error]     val resultMaybe: Try[CommandResult] = cmd.meta.shell match {
[error]                                                    ^
```

Comment: I think I found an answer, but it has a couple of oddities, including multiple parameter lists, not using an implicit val argument to the class, and of course, `asInstanceOf` ... will try to post the solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, cause there is quite a lot going on, but it looks like the implicit conversion `JobDispatch` is recursively calling itself. Why don't you do it like this? Calling `meta` directly, instead of `job.meta`.

```
  trait Job[J] {
    def id(jb: J): JobId
    def cmd(jb: J): String
    type M <: JobMetaData
    type JRef = J
    def meta(jb: J): M
    def pickler: Pickler[J]
    def rw: RW[J]
    def instance(jb: J, id: JobId, cmd: String, meta: M): J
  }
  object Job{

    type Aux[J0, M0] = Job[J0] {type M = M0}
    implicit class JobDispatch[J](val job: J)(implicit val ev: Job[J]) {
      def id: JobId = ev.id(job)
      def cmd: String = ev.cmd(job)
      def meta: ev.M = ev.meta(job)
      def rw: RW[J] = ev.rw
      def copyJob(
        idIn: JobId = id,
        cmdIn: String = cmd,
        metaIn: ev.M = meta
      ): J = ev.instance(job, idIn, cmdIn, metaIn)
    }
  }
```